# Error when .loc() rows with a list of dates in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-loc

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web

df = web.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo')
df['pct'] = df['Close'].pct_change()

dates_list = df.index[df['pct'].gt(0.002)]

df2 = web.DataReader('^GDAXI', 'yahoo')
df2['pct2'] = df2['Close'].pct_change()
```

i was trying to run this:

```
df2.loc[dates_list, 'pct2']
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported,
```

I am guessing this is because there are missing data for dates in `dates_list`. To resolve this:

```
    idx1 = df.index
    idx2 = df2.index
    missing = idx2.difference(idx1)
    df.drop(missing, inplace = True)
    df2.drop(missing, inplace = True)
```

However i am still getting the same error. I dont understand why that is.

Comment: Are there index values in your dates_list that are not in df2?

Comment: Yes there are but I tried to remove them with difference()

Comment: Perhaps you could get around this problem by resetting the indexes on both dataframes and filtering the dates using `df.loc[df['dates'].isin(dates_list),'pct2']`. I do not believe the method you are trying will work if there are any index values in the date_list that are not in your df2, and although your fix might solve that problem, it's hard to say without seeing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *dates_list* has been created from *df*, so it includes
some dates present in index **there** (in *df*).

Then you read *df2* and attempt to retrieve *pct2* from rows on
just these dates.

But there is a chance that the index in *df2* does **not** contain
all dates given in *dates_list*.
And just this is the cause of your exception.

To avoid it, retrieve only rows on dates **present** in the index.
To look for only such "allowed" (narrow down the rows specifidation),
you should pass:

```
dates_list[dates_list.isin(df2.index)]
```

Run this alone and you will see the "allowed" dates (some dates will
be eliminated).

So change the offending instruction to:

```
df2.loc[dates_list[dates_list.isin(df2.index)], 'pct']
```

Comment: Yes that makes more sense than what i was doing. Thanks!